# Update File By columns

Tags: c++, file

I am reading a large File **f1**: 10,000 lines and 47,000 columns. What I want to do is to transpose **f1** and save into **f2**.

To solve this problem what I did is the following:

- Step 1: Read **f1** line by line
- Step 2: Write line to **f2**, and here is the problem i want to update **f2** by columns not by lines.

The following image illustrates what i want to do, so i read line 1 and write it into file 2, Then I read line 2 and write it into f2 **( by columns not by rows)**

**Question:** How can I write into a new file by columns not by rows.

This is where i am so far:

```
int main()
{

       int size = A.weightedKeys.size();
        ifstream file("f1.txt");
        ofstream fout("f2.txt");
        float x;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            vector<float> v;
            for (size_t j = 0; j < A.names.size(); j++)
            {
                file >> x;
                v.push_back(x);

            }
            //Each time that i have a new vector i want to add it by column to f2 not by rows
            for(size_t k = 0; k < v.size();k++ )
            {
               fout << v[k]<< endl;
            }
            v.clear();

        }
        fout.close();
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file is really nothing more than a large array of consecutive bytes, so as far as the storage is concerned there is no concept of either "rows" nor "columns". We just say that a new row begins after a '\n'.

Unfortunately, this also means that you can't write to files in column-major format, since you can't insert data into the middle of a file.

Two options I can think of:

1) load the entire input file into memory and then write it out in a transposed manner (~2GB for your use case, which should be OK).

2) read through the input file once, storing the start of each line (using tellg) in a vector, then create your new file by iterating over the vector (calling seekg on the value), then reading and writing to your output file, at the same time updating the position in the vector.

Comment: Oh ok I see @zennehoy. well that sounds a good idea. So in **c++** we can't do that. And Can i just use a vector of vectors to represent the file when i load it, into memory?

Comment: @HaniGoc You can't do this in any language - the layout of files is not something that depends on the language. Does each line have the same number of columns? If so, I would recommend loading it all into one large vector (rows*columns), but using a vector of vectors would also work (despite requiring a bit more memory).

Comment: I understand @zennehoy I'll do it this way then. 

Thank you.

Comment: What would you recommand, sorry for this last comment. for example boost multiarray?

Comment: @HaniGoc I'd stick to the regular C++ stdlib for this, no need for an external library. If you are using boost already, sure, you can use multiarray, but just `std::vector<float> v(rows*cols);` would be enough. You can then access any position by `v[r*cols + c]`.